# D3js - draw RGB image histogram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to make a color histogram of uploaded images but my histogram won't draw, what should I do?
Here is the function that loops through the pixels of the image

```
let rD={}, gD={}, bD={};
let cv = document.getElementById("C");
let ctx = cv.getContext("2d");
cv.width = img.width;
cv.height = img.height;
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
let pixelSum={};
const iD=ctx.getImageData(0, 0, cv.width, cv.height).data;
for (var i=0; i<256; i++) { rD[i]=0; gD[i]=0; bD[i]=0; }
for (var i=0; i<=765; i++) { pixelSum[i]=0; }
for (var i=0; i<iD.length; i+=4) {
pixelSum[iD[i]+iD[i+1]+iD[i+2]]++;
rD[iD[i]]++;
gD[iD[i+1]]++;
bD[iD[i+2]]++;
}
histogram({pixelSum, rD, gD,bD});
```

And here's the histogram function:

```
let W=800
let H=W/2;
const svg = d3.select('svg');
const margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50};
const width = W - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = H - margin.top - margin.bottom;
let q = document.querySelector('svg');
q.style.width=width;
q.style.height=height;
if (yAxis) { d3.selectAll("g.y-axis").remove(); yAxis=false; }
function graphComponent(data, color) {
  d3.selectAll(".bar-"+color).remove();
  var data = Object.keys(data).map(function(key){ return {freq:data[key],   idx:+key}});
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.idx; })]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0])
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.freq; })]);
var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
if (!yAxis) {
  yAxis=true;
  g.append("g")
   .attr("class", "y-axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + -5 + ",0)")
   .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10).tickSizeInner(10).tickSizeOuter(2));
}
g.selectAll(".bar-"+color)
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar-"+color)
  .attr("fill", color)
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.idx); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.freq); })
  .attr("width", 2)
  .attr("opacity", 0.8)
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.freq); })    
}
graphComponent(data.gD, "green");
graphComponent(data.bD, "blue");
   graphComponent(data.rD, "red");
  }
```

Here is also a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EdmoZw

Comment: I have no problem running the codepen, the ++r/g/b buttons do not much but the histogram draws on my Chrome

Comment: **typo**: Unit-less CSS `width` and `height` value is part of the new SVG2 specs, that is not widely supported yet (I think only webkits/Blink have it currently). So simply add an unit: `q.style.width=W + "px"; q.style.height=H + "px";`